# Create a pie with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, pie-chart

Hello I have this code with Python :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_a = 0.004095232
total_b = 0.05075945
total_c = 0.005425
total_d = 0.022948572
total_e = 0.015012

slices = [total_a,total_b,total_c,total_d,total_e]
activities = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']
cols = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue', 'orangered']
plt.pie(slices,labels=activities,autopct='%1.1f%%',colors=cols,startangle=140,shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

But I get this when I execute this code :

[image: Pie]

I don't understand why I don't get a full pie ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer below with an explanation of the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html), plt.py takes an array input and will normalise the values for you as long as the sum of the elements is greater than 1.

Since your values sum to less than 1 the array is not normalised. In order to normalise yourself you should should divide each element by the largest value of the list with the following line:

```
slices = [aSlice/max(slices) for aSlice in slices]
```

And I would put this in your program here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_a = 0.004095232
total_b = 0.05075945
total_c = 0.005425
total_d = 0.022948572
total_e = 0.015012


slices = [total_a,total_b,total_c,total_d,total_e]
slices = [aSlice/max(slices) for aSlice in slices]

activities = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']
cols = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue', 'orangered']
plt.pie(slices,labels=activities,autopct='%1.1f%%',colors=cols,startangle=140,shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

For me this then produces a graph like this:

[image: The properly rendered pie chart]

Answer (score 2):

The `x` argument to `pie(x, ...)` distingishes two cases. As [the documentation states](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html):

> Make a pie chart of array x. The fractional area of each wedge is given by x/sum(x). If sum(x) < 1, then the values of x give the fractional area directly and the array will not be normalized. The resulting pie will have an empty wedge of size 1 - sum(x).

In the case from the question, the sum is indeed smaller one `sum(x) < 1`. An easy workaround may be to multiply the input array by some large number or divide it by its sum.

```
slices = np.array([total_a,total_b,total_c,total_d,total_e])*100
```

or

```
slices = np.array([total_a,total_b,total_c,total_d,total_e])
slices /= slices.sum()
```